# Insert a record using AJAX inside a bootstrap modal window

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, modal-dialog

I have a modal window that allows users to dynamically search a site list. It uses ajax to return a list of sites by keystroke. When the list is returned I'd like the user to be able to click on a button and record the site ID in a database to create a favourites list.
I can achieve this using a link and passing the ID of the site to the receiving query, but of course the result doesn't appear in the model window.
Any idea how I do this? I have tried using a form to process the data using ajax again, but it only added the first site ID in the list, regardless of the other records.

I'm using Coldfusion to add and retrieve data, and Bootstrap 3 to display it.

This is my current code to retrieve sites:

```
function runSearchF(str)
{
var si = document.getElementById("sites").checked;
var xmlhttp;
if (str.length==0)
  {
  document.getElementById("searchResultsF").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("searchResultsF").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","_ajax/ajax_FavouriteSite.cfm?q="+str+"&m="+si,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and the page handling the output:

```
<cfoutput query="getSiteName">

<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" name="Site" value="#Name#" class="form-control" readonly />  
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a href="action_addFavourites.cfm?EN=#EquipmentNoFull#" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Add to Favourites</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Regards
Neil

Comment: You're missing a lot of details here.  Offhand, you are setting the html of the searchResultsF rather than appending to it, which is likely why it is only showing one (the last one clicked).  change innerHTML = to be innerHTML += and see what you get.